# while loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to use while loop, i wonder if there are any syntax changes in jQuery

**in javascript**

```
  var text = "";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

how can i perform loop in jquery just like this?

Comment: same approach. Nothing gets changed.

Comment: "i had to use tools for building now looking forward need to use hammer for building. how can i perform building with hammer"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference between javascript and jquery in case of `while loop`

```js
$(function () {
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i++;
    }
    $("#demo").html(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same in jQuery.

There is a popular [loop method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) in jQuery, but it doesn't apply to your example. `$.each()` allows you to loop through arrays and array-like objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javescript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i++;
    }}); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference in javascript and jquery while loops.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var text = "";
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    text += "<br>The number is " + i;
    i++;
}});
```

This will work.